# Unit test Controller Phalcon

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, phalcon

What's the difference between

```
$this->userService->getUser();
```

and

```
$this->di->get('userService')->getUser();
```

I use this in a controller.

I know that the first variant is a magic function, but how does it works?
When I am testing the controller using PhpUnit, only the second variant works.

Answer (score -1):

Difference only in details, when you call `$this->userService` php execute magic method `__call` and return you same object from di.

By the way, there are not good practice to testing controllers.

Comment: What do you mean by "there are not good practice to testing controllers"?